# on  the Axiom of Choice and the Spectrum of Rings 

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice

consider the following theorem, when $R$ is a commutative ring with a non-zero identity:

**A ring $R$ is zero-dimensional if and only if $\mbox{Spec(R)}$ is Hausdorff.**

The proof uses the Axiom of Choice. So, I am wondering if this theorem is equivalent to the Axiom of choice or not.

Comment: What is the motivation of this question?

Comment: Choice is often used in such situation for the sole purpose of giving the spectrum points. It can very often be avoided. What is "the proof" you are referring to?

Comment: This depends on precise definitions. How do you define zero-dimensional ring? Every prime ideal is maximal? In terms of lengths of chains of prime ideals?

Comment: @François: By zero-dimensional I mean every prime ideal is maximal. 

Comment: @Martin: I am interested in algebraic equivalents of AC. So as an old habit whenever I see an application of AC I ask myself is that necessary to use AC ? In this particular problem, I don't know the  answer. 


Comment: @chatish: Have you considered using the other definition instead? Then the result is trivial. Maximal ideals can be very ill-behaved without the axiom of choice and all you really care about are prime ideals, which aren't as ill-behaved.